# How to kill Statement Runner in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

May I ask how to stop the Statement Runner in SQL Developer (Ver 19.4.0.354 Build 354.1759. Database Version 12.1.0.2)?

[image: Statement Runner]

SQL Developer have started a dummy StatementRunner Task since yesterday and have been running for 16 Hours. I tried to pause it as I don't want to close my SQL Developer while in the middle of running a SQL file with many scripts.

I tried to use Monitor Session tool by starting a new SQL Developer this morning and I find that there was only one active session to the database, which is the session used by the Monitor Session tool.

[image]

That means the Statement Runner Task from the other SQL Developer was actually not doing anything, but simply hold up the entire application.

Of course, for this time, I have kind of no choice but to kill the old SQL Developer instance using Windows Task Manager. However, as this is very common to me. Is there anyway to avoid it in future?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Version of SQL Developer and database?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Thanks for your comment. SQL Developer Ver 19.4.0.354 Build 354.1759. Database Version 12.1.0.2. I have just added to the question. Thanks!

Comment: I would try upgrading, your software is 2 years old. Free process, so can't hurt.

Comment: Will try. Thanks!